# Phonegap(cordova) Pushplugin Silent Notification - Android

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, phonegap-pushplugin

I am working on a chat application using phonegap for android, which is already running over web. I am sending messages through pushnotification and everything is working fine and notification is coming in status bar with default device sound setting. Now I want to sync some data from server without notifying user, means I need a notification that should just tell me that there is some new data on server to sync, without having status bar notification. I searched over web but couldn't found anything which can help me.

Any help would be great..

Thanks 
Jaya

Comment: Develop a background service, not push notification.

Comment: I am trying background services for updating new data on server...Thanks :) I found that while application is open notifications don't come in status bar, is there anyway to forcefully send them as status bar notification?

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the plugin to not create a notification if a certain variable is set.

If you are using [PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin):

A notification is created only if you send `message` in the payload. But you will receive the payload in your application's callback. You can use this effectively to communicate with your application with having to implement anything additional.